# NGXS use input value as id to filtering lazy selector

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have a `CommentBoxComponent` that displays all the comments of the post in the containing `PostComponent`. I'm getting the id of the post from the containing parent component via an `@Input` field.
The idea of the `CommentBoxComponent` is to display a `CommentComponent` for each of the comments of the post.
I'm trying to achieve that by writing a lazy selector that will receive the id of the post and return the filtered comments.
The problem is that while I'm setting the lazy selector in the component's constructor, the input id has not been set yet.
If I try setting the lazy selector in `ngOnChanges`, it's already too late, and the selection has already taken place.

Here's the component's code:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class CommentBoxComponent {
    @Input() 
    post: Post;

    comments$: Observable<Comment[]>;     

    constructor(private store: Store) { 
        let filter = filterFn => filterFn(this.post.id); // this.post is undefined at this stage

        this.comments$ = this.store.select(CommentState.postComments).pipe(map(filter));
    }
}
```

Here's the selector's code:

```
@Selector()
static postComments(state: CommentStateModel) {
    return (postId: string) => {
        return state.comments.filter(comment => comments.postId === postId);
    };
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use `ngOnInit` here to initialise `comments$`.

When it is called, any `@Input` bindings will be completed so the value for `this.post` will be set.

```
ngOnInit() { 
 this.comments$ = this.store.select(CommentState.postComments)
   .pipe(
      map(fn => fn(this.post.id))
    );
}
```

Lifecycle details here [OnInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit)

Comment: That's the first thing I've tried, but even when the component is ready, it doesn't mean that the value, which is set asynchronously, is already set. I found the bug (see my answer above). +1 for the effort though !

Comment: Ah I see, that's a little different to the way I'd used it so far. Glad you found the solution anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, so I'm sharing here in case anyone's interested.
I was wrong to assume that calling `store.select` after the construction doesn't work (it just hit me that there's no reason for it to be any different than calling it during `ngOnChanges`).

It turns out that the selection was working just fine, but the reason I didn't get any results was that I didn't dispatch a `FetchComments` action before the selection. 
That means that I always got 0 commens back ...

I just want to clarify that in such a case, the correct place to do the selection, is either in the setter of the `@Input` or during `ngOnChanges` where you can verify that the value of the input is valid.
If you try to place the selection in `ngOnInit`, the `@Input` might not have been initialized yet in case of an asynchronoud initialization.